# ng-show speed in ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing **ionic** application and I have a problem with **angular ng-show**

I have 4 elements for which I use ng-show according to some conditions
my problem is that at the first glance all elements are shown and then just those which satisfy the conditions show.

**Is there a way to increase the speed of ng-show evaluating my conditions or maybe any other alternative that solves my problem?**

Comment: I am assuming that you populate your model after an ajax call, so I'd say you just have to make sure your conditions evaluate to `false` before you get the values.

Comment: Is it during the startup of the app the elements are shown briefly? If so, you can use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)